# Laravel 5.6 OneToOne relation not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a BuildingImage model with a OneToOne relation to BuildingType:

BuildImage Model:

```
/**
 * Get the source type of the Building Image.
 */
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\BuildingType');
}
```

BuildingType Model:

```
/**
 * Get the Building Image that owns the building type.
 */
public function buildingImage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BuildingImage');
}
```

My tables:

building_images table -> source is the building type id

[image: source is the building type id]

building_types table

[image]

When I try to do this in my controller just to test:
(an ImageRequest has one or more Builings and a Building has one BuildingType)

```
$imageRequest = ImageRequest::findOrFail($id);

$buildings = $imageRequest->buildingImages;

foreach ($buildings as $building) {
    dd($building->type);
}
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'building_types.building_image_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *
>   from `building_types` where `building_types`.`building_image_id` = 45
>   and `building_types`.`building_image_id` is not null limit 1)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BuildImage model should be

/**
 * Get the source type of the Building Image.
 */

```
public function type() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\BuildingType',"id","source"); 
}
```

And BuildingType Model should be

/**
 * Get the Building Image that owns the building type.
 */

```
public function buildingImage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BuildingImage',"source","id");
}
```

This should work.
For more info have a look
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score 3):

That's because by default laravel will look for a primary key named `{model}_id`, and given that you are using a different column name (`source`), you need to specify when defining the relationship:

As the documentation [states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one):

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the `Phone` model is automatically assumed to have a `user_id` foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the `hasOne` method:
>
> ```
> return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');
> ```
>
> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the `id` (or the custom `$primaryKey`) column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the user's id column in the `user_id` column of the `Phone` record. If you would like the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third argument to the `hasOne` method specifying your custom key:
>
> ```
> return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
> ```

---

Now that that is clear. Let's talk about the relationship itself.

You are defining that a `BuildImage` has one `BuildingType`. But with that logic, the foreign key should be stored in the `building_types` table, and not the other way around (`source` column appears in the `building_images` table). And -I'm just assuming that- many `BuildImage` can belongs to an specific `BuildingType`. So, if this assumption is correct:

- a `BuildImage` belongs to a specific `BuildingType`.
- a `BuildinType` can be specify in many `BuildImage`s

So, you should define your relationship like this:

**BuildImage.php**

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BuildingType', 'source');
}
```

**BuildingType.php**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BuildingImage::class, 'source');
}
```

Comment: So I have to fill in "source" in the "foreign_key" in your code example?

Comment: @Michael I'll update. But I thing that you should define your relationship a little bit different.

Comment: You can also use the class instead of a string, which some (myself included) tend to prefer.  `return $this->hasOne(App\Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

Comment: @JohnHalsey yes, indeed. Nice observation, I'll include it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to indicate the index ID like this?

```
public function buildingImage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BuildingImage', 'image_request_id');
}
```

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the
>   model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to
>   have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention,
>   you may pass the second argument to the hasOne method:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one